# How to import a custom component in an Ionic 4 page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a page in Ionic 4, (`IntroPage`) which uses a custom component (`intro-task`).

Angular complains  about intro-task:

```
Can't bind to 'active' since it isn't a known property of 'intro-task'.
1. If 'intro-task' is an Angular component and it has 'active' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'intro-task' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<div id="intro">
```

although I am adding it to `intro.page.module`. I want to avoid adding it to `app.module.ts`.

The page is:

```
intro.page.html
---------------
<intro-task number=1 [active]="task1Active" (click)="gotoTask1()">
  task 1
</intro-task>

<intro-task number=2 [active]="task2Active" (click)="gotoTask2()">
  task 2
</intro-task>


<intro-task number=3 [active]="task3Active" (click)="gotoTask3()">
  task 3
</intro-task>
```

The following attempts do not seem to work:

A. Import `IntroTaskComponent` into `intro.module.ts`. I even added an entryComponents property, but to no avail

```
intro.module.ts
--------------
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { IntroPage } from './intro.page';
import { IntroTaskComponent} from '../intro-task/intro-task.component'

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IntroPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    IntroPage, 
    IntroTaskComponent

  ],
  entryComponents:[
    IntroTaskComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    IntroPage,

  ]
})
export class IntroPageModule {}
```

B. Create a `intro-task.component.module` and import that

```
intro-task.component.module.ts
------------------------------

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IntroTaskComponent } from './intro-task.component';
import {IonicModule} from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IntroTaskComponent,


  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
  ],

  exports:[

    IntroTaskComponent
  ]

})
export class IntroTaskComponentModule {}



intro.module.ts
---------------

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { IntroPage } from './intro.page';
import { IntroTaskComponentModule} from '../intro-task/intro-task.component.module'

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IntroPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
    IntroTaskComponentModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    IntroPage, 


  ],

  exports:[
    IntroPage,

  ]
})
export class IntroPageModule {}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I import IntroTaskComponent properly in a lazy-loading kind of manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your selector 'intro-task' is something different inside the IntroTaskComponent component.

Comment: turns out ionic4 names components differently from ionic3 :/

Comment: how is that? Can you share some link?